# How to get out of Apple IIe mode on Macintosh Color Classic?

Tags: apple-ii, apple-macintosh

I just picked-up a Macintosh Color Classic with an Apple IIe card. I've never used one of these before but was able to get it to enter into Apple IIe mode. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get out of this mode. I tried `exit` and common keyboard shortcuts, but wasn't able to do it.

However, one shortcut (I believe it was Command-Power) resulted in a popup window on top of the Apple IIe screen like so:

[image]

Sorry for the image distortion; appears to be a screen refresh issue. It appears this is some kind of command prompt, but everything I try (exit, quit, q, etc.) doesn't do anything.

Does anyone know how I can exit this popup screen as well as exit the Apple IIe mode? I don't want to pull the plug, but not sure what else I can do.

Thank you.

Comment: I think either "q" or "x" or "quit" or "exit" to get out of the Mac Debug monitor window. Then, there's a hotkey to toggle you from the Apple //e mode back to the configuration menu for it - I think it is Cmd+Esc, maybe?

Comment: Thanks @BrianH. However, I tried those keys and they do not work to exit the debug window (is that what this is?). I type those, press enter, then it just deletes the line and does nothing else.

Comment: Ah, It's "G", then Return, to exit the debug window. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacsBug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Apple IIe Card Owner's Guide](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIe_Card_Owners_Guide/page/n55/mode/2up), <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> will open the Option Panel, which includes buttons to "Quit IIe" and "Restart IIe", among other things.

Answer (score 4):

The window shown on the screen shot is **not** MacsBug, but some badly documented, most likely ROM resident debugging facility popping up when MacsBug is not installed. @BrianH mentions correctly to get out of that window with G and Return, though.

Comment: Poorly documented, eh? Check out Technical Note 1136 which describes all the commands. For example mirrored at https://www.fenestrated.net/mirrors/Apple%20Technotes%20(As%20of%202002)/tn/tn1136.html

Comment: Originally written as Technote 38 "ROM Debugger."

Comment: Back in the 1990's, there were mainly Manuals and Books. Every program you bought had a manual. Books (like Inside Macintosh) sometimes served the purpose of a manual. I don't know about Technotes being available without requiring some sort of online access. So, I conclude, **compared** to yesterdays standards, it's poorly documented.

Comment: Addition: According to the TN, MicroBug is mentioned in the MacsBug Manual. I can't recall this, even if I've read it some time ago.